# Subsetting data.table by values with repetition

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to subset data.table in a way which would provide some rows repeatedly. This works well with indices but I am not sure how to do it in a simple way with values especially when the values does not appear in one row only.

E.g.:

```
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(x1=c('a','a','b','b','c','c'),x2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
xsel<-c('a','b','a','a','c','b')
dt[x1%in%xsel,]
```

will provide this output:

```
   x1 x2
1:  a  1
2:  a  2
3:  b  3
4:  b  4
5:  c  5
6:  c  6
```

I would like to get it in the original order and with repetition exactly as it is in the `xsel` vector. Is it possible to do it in a reasonably simple way without looping? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
setkey(dt, x1)  # set the key
dt[J(xsel)]     # or: dt[.(xsel)]
```

gives:

> ```
>     x1 x2
>  1:  a  1
>  2:  a  2
>  3:  b  3
>  4:  b  4
>  5:  a  1
>  6:  a  2
>  7:  a  1
>  8:  a  2
>  9:  c  5
> 10:  c  6
> 11:  b  3
> 12:  b  4
> ```

Without setting the key, you could use:

```
dt[.(xsel), on = .(x1)]
```

Comment: I guess one might need allow.cartesian=TRUE for some cases like this.